# batch using 7-zip: compress smallest file first to largest file

Tags: 7zip

I have a .bat file that runs 7-zip to compress all files in a directory.  The files range in size from 1mb to 500mb and there are 10 files.  Every 15 mins a scheduled backup program overwrites 5 of the 10 files.  Those 5 files are usually the smallest and the quickest to compress, but 7-zip starts with the largest file first thus missing the 5 files within the 15 minutes.  How do I get 7-zip to start with the smallest file first. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
c:
cd "\Program Files\7-Zip"
7z a C:\WEBDATA C:\FILE1.BAK C:\FILE2.BAK C:\FILE3 C:\FILE4 C:\FILE5 etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

If all of the files are in the same directory, you can use the sort feature of the `dir` command to add files to the archive one at a time.

For example, if the files to back up are in a subdirectory called 'files':

```
for /f %%N in ('"dir /A-D /O:S /B files"') do (
   7z a backup.7z files/%%N
)
```

Based on your description this should be sufficient, but if the files are in various locations you may need to get fancier.  I haven't tried it myself, but I would expect you could loop through a list of directories, writing each size / filename to a temporary file, then using the `sort` command on that file.